# Elasticsearch Scroll

Tags: elasticsearch, scroll, pagination

I am little bit confused over Elasticsearch by its scroll functionality.
In elasticsearch is it possible to call search API everytime whenever the user scrolls on the result set?
From documentation

```
"search_type" => "scan",    // use search_type=scan
"scroll" => "30s",          // how long between scroll requests. should be small!
"size" => 50,               // how many results *per shard* you want back
```

Is that mean it will perform search for every 30 seconds and returns all the sets of results until there is no records?

For example my ES returns total 500 records. I am getting an data from ES as two sets of records each with 250 records. Is there any way I can display first set of 250 records first, when user scrolls then second set of 250 records.Please suggest

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What you are looking for is pagination.

You can achieve your objective by querying for a fixed size and setting the `from` parameter. Since you want to set display in batches of 250 results, you can set `size = 250` and with each consecutive query, increment the value of `from` by `250`.

```
GET /_search?size=250                     ---- return first 250 results
GET /_search?size=250&from=250            ---- next 250 results 
GET /_search?size=250&from=500            ---- next 250 results
```

On the contrary, `Scan & scroll` lets you retrieve a large set of results with a single search and is ideally meant for operations like re-indexing data into a new index. Using it for displaying search results in real-time is not recommended.

To explain `Scan & scroll` briefly, what it essentially does is that it scans the index for the query provided with the scan request and returns a `scroll_id`. This `scroll_id` can be passed to the next scroll request to return the next batch of results.

Consider the following example-

```py
    # Initialize the scroll
    page = es.search(
      index = 'yourIndex',
      doc_type = 'yourType',
      scroll = '2m',
      search_type = 'scan',
      size = 1000,
      body = {
        # Your query's body
        }
    )
    sid = page['_scroll_id']
    scroll_size = page['hits']['total']
      
    # Start scrolling
    while (scroll_size > 0):
      print "Scrolling..."
      page = es.scroll(scroll_id = sid, scroll = '2m')
      # Update the scroll ID
      sid = page['_scroll_id']
      # Get the number of results that we returned in the last scroll
      scroll_size = len(page['hits']['hits'])
      print "scroll size: " + str(scroll_size)
      # Do something with the obtained page
```

In above example, following events happen-

- Scroller is initialized. This returns the first batch of results along with the scroll_id
- For each subsequent scroll request, the updated `scroll_id` (received in the previous scroll request) is sent and next batch of results is returned.
- Scroll time is basically the time for which the search context is kept alive. If the next scroll request is not sent within the set timeframe, the search context is lost and results will not be returned. This is why it should not be used for real-time results display for indexes with a huge number of docs.

Comment: what does scroll = '2m' means? Does it mean 2 minutes? What is the use of it?

Comment: @AmoghMishra yes it means 2 minutes

Comment: @AmoghMishra scroll takes a snapshot of the of the query, and that's how long it's stored in memory.  This means if you add/update records, subsequent scrolls will not see them.

Comment: "search_type=scan" was deprecated, and in v5.0 removed. You don't need it

Comment: do you expect sid to be different each time?  i am getting same sid each time.  what would be the problem?

Comment: The scroll parameter (passed to the search request and to every scroll request) tells Elasticsearch how long it should keep the search context alive. Its value (e.g. 1m, see Time units) does not need to be long enough to process all data — it just needs to be long enough to process the previous batch of results. Each scroll request (with the scroll parameter) sets a new expiry time. If a scroll request doesn’t pass in the scroll parameter, then the search context will be freed as part of that scroll request.

Answer (score 16):

You are understanding wrong the purpose of the `scroll` property. It does not mean that elasticsearch will fetch next page data after 30 seconds. When you are doing first scroll request you need to specify when scroll context should be closed. `scroll` parameter is telling to close scroll context after 30 seconds.

After doing first scroll request you will get back `scroll_id`parameter in response. For next pages you need to pass that value to get next page of the scroll response. If you will not do the next scroll request within 30 seconds, the scroll request will be closed and you will not be able to get next pages for that scroll request.

Comment: Is the previous scroll_id and its context cleared automatically when the new scroll_id and context is generated or all scroll_ids and their contexts remain active till the specified time expires or all the data has been scrolled through ?

Comment: ids will remain active till the end of specified time, you can have multiple scroll context and each one will have its life

Answer (score 14):

What you described as an example use case is actually [search results pagination](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-from-size.html), which is available for any search query and is limited by 10k results. `scroll` requests are needed for the cases when you need to go over that 10k limit, with `scroll` query you can fetch even the entire collection of documents.

Probably the source of confusion here is that `scroll` term is ambiguous: it means the type of a query, and also it is a name of a parameter of such query (as was mentioned in [other comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46607490/5095957), it is time ES will keep waiting for you to fetch next chunk of scrolling).

`scroll` queries are heavy, and should be avoided until absolutely necessary. In fact, in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-scroll.html)
 it says:

> Scrolling is not intended for real time user requests, but rather for processing large amounts of data, ...

Now regarding your another question:

> In elasticsearch is it possible to call search API everytime whenever the user scrolls on the result set?

Yes, even several [parallel scroll requests](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-scroll.html)
are possible:

> Each scroll is independent and can be processed in parallel like any scroll request.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of the [Scroll API at elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-scroll) explains this behaviour also.

The result size of 10k is a default value and can be overwritten during runtime, if necessary:

```
PUT { "index" : { "max_result_window" : 500000} }
```

The life time of the scroll id is defined in each scroll request with the parameter "scroll", e.g.

```
..
  "scroll" : "5m"
  ..
```

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Elasticsearch, you'll use [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/paginate-search-results.html#search-after). The `keep_alive` you set there, much like the `timeout` in the scroll, is only the time needed for you to process one page.

That's because Elasticsearch will keep your "search context" alive for that amount of time, then removes it. Also, Elasticsearch won't fetch the next page for you automatically, you'll have to do that by sending requests with the ID from the last request.

Answer (score 0):

It is wise to use the scroll api as one can not get more than 10K data at a time in elasticsearch.