# elasticsearch how to get previous data using scroll

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

I used this sample for making a pagination function

```
    POST /twitter/_search?scroll=1m
        {
            "size": 100,
            "query": {
                "match" : {
                    "title" : "elasticsearch"
                }
            }
        }



    POST  /_search/scroll 
        {
            "scroll" : "1m", 
            "scroll_id" : "DXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBAAAAAAAAAD4WYm9laVYtZndUQlNsdDcwakFMNjU1QQ==" 
        }
```

But there is one problem
This code can get next data but not previous data how should I solve this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use pagination you should rather use [From / Size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) than scroll.

You can refer also to this answer : [Elasticsearch Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604207/elasticsearch-scroll#answer-46618122) it explain the difference with scan and scroll

Comment: i used From / size but it's limited 10,000 data so i must be scroll or search_after thank you for answer have a good day

Comment: You could change the index.max_result_window setting but I don't think this is a good idea as your server could become overloaded. Scroll is definitely not intended to be used for real time queries (and I think that you want to do real time as you want to get back). You have two choices then : reduce the number of result of your query to go beyond 10000 (with  "size" : 10000) or tell the user that there is more than 10000 results and that he has to refine his search.

Comment: I try change setting for index.max can i give set up the setting option guide or some link?

Comment: I don't recommend it at all but if you want to change the setting here is how to do it https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html and here is a guide on options : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html