# elasticsearch.scroll() shows hits but returns empty result if they were returned by scroll

Tags: elasticsearch

I am hitting an elastic database and I want to return results one by one using `scroll()`, which requires me to fetch a `scroll_id` using the `search()` method.

The result size can range from 0-40000, that's why I can't use `search()` for the whole thing.

I didn't notice the problem when there were a large number of hits, but when there is only one hit, the scroll doesn't return anything.

```
query = {"query":{"match":{"message": "Techtotic"}}, "sort": [{"@timestamp":"asc"}]}

scrollid = es.search(index="ts-shanks*", size=2, scroll="50m", body=query)

hits = scrollid["hits"]["total"]

scrollid = scrollid["_scroll_id"]

for i in range(hits):

    entry = es.scroll(scroll_id=scrollid, scroll="1m", filter_path=req_data)

    try:
        print(entry["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["message"])

    except Exception:
        print(json.dumps(entry, indent=4))
```

The output displays the matched hit in the print corresponding to the '''search()''' but not in the one with the `scroll()`.

Also, no matter how many hits, we get the last output of the scroll always triggers the except block because it's empty.

I heard that `search_type="scan"` would fix it, but it seams that it has been deprecated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604207/elasticsearch-scroll)

Comment: Yeah, it would have solved my problem with the ```search_type='scan'``` but scan doesn't seem to be a viable value for this argiment. The doc says:```:arg search_type: Search operation type, valid choices are:
            'query_then_fetch', 'dfs_query_then_fetch'```

Comment: Does it work without `filter_path`? If so, can you use source filtering rather than filter_path?

Comment: It still has the same problem when i remove filter path.